# Pyinstaller on Kali to create exe for Windows XP

Tags: python, linux, windows, exe

I am using Pyinstaller on Kali Linux 2 to create .exe to run on Windows XP.

So far, pyinstaller is successful at creating .exe that works on Kali Linux, but not Windows

Here is the python code

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://www.cnn.com')
```

This is the command I ran on Kali Linux

```
~/Downloads/PyInstaller-3.2/pyinstaller.py --onefile --windowed --noupx open.py
```

When I open the resulting open.exe in Kali, it opens `www.cnn.com`. But if I email this attachment and open in Windows XP, it asks

[image]

When I save and try to execute, it says ..... How to troubleshoot this?

[image]

And when I click open is shows following. How to make it open with double-click?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#supporting-multiple-operating-systems):

> If you need to distribute your application for more than one OS, for example both Windows and Mac OS X, you must install PyInstaller on each platform and bundle your app separately on each.

So, to make an app which runs on Windows, you have to create it using PyInstaller on Windows.

Comment: @rafalmpIf I understand correctly, if I want exe to run on an end-user's Windows XP, I need to create the exe on my own Windows XP (so the required files are present). Then the end user can download my exe and run it on their machine. Please clarify

Comment: Yes, or create it on a virtual machine with Windows XP running.

Answer (score 2):

Rafalmp is correct you must use a Windows machine to compile it. Alternatively you can use Wine, if you didn't have access to a Windows machine.

For more info please refer to [Pyinstaller FAQ](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Defender assumes that externally sourced executables, especially those without cryptographic signature, may be malware. Try clicking "Open."

Comment: It asks what application I'd like to open with. Please see my updated question.

Comment: By the way, the Windows XP isn't running AV (this is my test machine on VMWare)